# How can I get sign bit of an integer in python?

Tags: python

I want to be able to access the sign bit of a number in python. I can do something like `n >> 31` in C since int is represented as 32 bits.

I can't make use of the conditional operator and > <.

Comment: `n < 0` perhaps?

Comment: [`numpy.signbit`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.signbit.html)

Answer (score 11):

in python 3 integers don't have a fixed size, and aren't represented using the internal CPU representation (which allows to handle very large numbers without trouble).

So the best way is

```
signbit = 1 if n < 0 else 0
```

or

```
signbit = int(n < 0)
```

EDIT: if you cannot use `<` or `>` (which is ludicrious but so be it) you could use the fact that `a-b` will be positive if a is greater than `b`, so you could do

```
abs(a-b) == a-b
```

that doesn't use `<` or `>` (at least in the text, because `abs` uses it you can trust me)

Comment: "_I can't make use of the conditional operator and > <_", he is most likely solving the interview question to get the max (or min) of two numbers without getting comparison operators.

Answer (score 3):

I would argue that in Python there is not really a concept of a sign bit. As far as the programmer is concerned, an `int` is just a type with certain behavior. You don't get access to the low-level representation. Even `bin(-3)` returns a "negative" binary representation: `'-0b11'`

However, there are ways to get the sign or the bigger if two integers without comparisons. The following approach abuses floating point math to avoid comparisons.

```
def sign(a):
    try:
        return (1 - int(a / (a**2)**0.5)) // 2
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        return 0

def return_bigger(a, b):
    s = sign(b - a)
    return a * s + b * (1 - s)


assert sign(-33) == 1
assert sign(33) == 0    

assert return_bigger(10, 15) == 15
assert return_bigger(25, 3) == 25
assert return_bigger(42, 42) == 42
```

- `(a**2)**0.5` could be replaced with `abs` but I bet internally this is implemented with a comparison.
- The `try`/`except` is not needed if you don't care about 0 or equal integers (or there may be another horrible math workaround).
- Finally, I'd like to point out that I have absolutely no idea why on earth anybody would want to implement something like that, except for the hell of it.

Comment: You are right. No one would want to do something like this. I am learning algorithms from a book called Cracking the coding interview. This book is based on Java. I am practicing with python. The question was more suitable for Jave.

Comment: @PraveenSinghYadav What I wanted to say is that my approach of replacing comparisons with floating point operations is very weird. Your question - doing something under certain restrictions - makes  perfect sense.

Answer (score 3):

Conceptually, the bit representation of a negative integer is padded with an infinite number of **1** bits to the left (just like a non-negative number is regarded as padded with an infinite number of **0** bits). The operation `n >> 31` does work (given that `n` is in the range of signed 32-bit numbers) in the sense that it places the sign bit (or if you prefer, one of the left-padding bits) in the lowest bit position. You just need to get rid of the rest of the left-padding bits, which you can do with a bitwise *and* operation like this:

```
n >> 31 & 1
```

Or you can make use of the fact that *all one bits* is how −1 is represented, and simply negate the result:

```
-(n >> 31)
```

Alternatively, you can cut off all but the lowest 32 **1** bits before you do the shift, like this:

```
(n & 0xffffffff) >> 31
```

This is all under the assumption that you are working with numbers that fit into a signed 32-bit int. If `n` might need a 64 bit representation, shift by 63 places instead of 31, and if it's just 16 bits numbers, shifting by 15 places is enoough. (If you use the `(n & 0xffffffff) >> 31` variant, adjust the number of `f`s accordingly).

On machine code level, *and*-ing/negating and shifting is potentially *much* more efficient than using comparison. The former is just a couple of machine instructions, while the latter would usually boil down to a *branch*. Branching doesn't just take more machine instructions, it also has a bad influence on the *pipelining* and *out-of-order execution* of modern CPUs. But Python execution takes place in a higher-level layer than machine code execution, and therefore it's difficult to say anything about the performance impact in Python: it may depend on the context – as it would in machine code – and may therefore also be difficult to test generally. (Caveat: I don't know much about how low-level execution happens in CPython, or in Python in general. For someone who does, this might not be so difficult to say.)

If you don't know how big `n` is (in Python, an integer is not required to fit into any specific number of bits), you can use `bit_length()` to find out. This will work for integers of any size:

```
-(n >> n.bit_length())
```

The `bit_length()` operation might boil down to a single machine instruction, or it might actually need a loop to find the result, depending on the implementation and the underlying machine architecture. In the latter case, this should be noticeably more costly than using a constant

Final remark: in C, `n >> 31` is actually not guaranteed to work like you assume, because the C language leaves it undefined whether `>>` does *logical* right shift (like you assume) or *arithmetic* shift right (like Python does). In some languages, these are different operators, which makes it clear what you get. In Java for instance, logical shift right is `>>>`, and arithmetic shift right is `>>`.

Answer (score -1):

How about this?

```
def is_negative(num, places):
    return not long(num * 10**places) & 0xFFFFFFFF == long(num * 10**places)
```

Not efficient, but not using < or > definitely restricts you to weirdness.  Note that zero will evaluate as positive.